# running jquery on images after page load

Tags: jquery, image-processing, autoresize

I have written a jQuery image resize script that works fine when the images are clicked using the handler, `$('img').click (function(){`. (see example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sambeckhamdesign/veQkL/25/))

However I want to set it to run as soon as the page is loaded but `$('img').load(function(){` doesn't work. (see example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sambeckhamdesign/ZVt4r/)) I'm assuming it's because it's running the script after the DOM has loaded but not the images. But If I'm honest I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').each(function() {
    // do your magic here
  });
});
```

Comment: This works but I've been told I should be using `$(window).load`

However that doesn't work lol.

Answer (score 0):

How about just running it under the normal `$(document).ready()` function? This will run when the page is fully loaded.

Comment: window load is the indicator that all images have downloaded (and hence the page is fully loaded), not doc ready

Comment: I don't think .ready() takes into account the actual images, just the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use $(document).ready because that only takes into account that the DOM is loaded. You need to use

```
$(window).load(
  function() {
  }
);
```